# Is there a way in Python to click a specific colored?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm very new to Python and coding
I've been trying to find a way to get one specific color and follow it with a simple click.
Is it possible to do a simple task like this and how would I go about doing this?

For example, I have an RGB value of R=92, G=75, B=44 somewhere on my screen and I want to automate a mouse click on it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest way to do it, but I am not sure if it works if you are using multiple monitors. It uses PIL.ImageGrab to make a "screenshot", and pyautogui to click on the target colour.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui
import time
import numpy as np


color = (228, 60, 47)           # target colour

image = ImageGrab.grab()        # grab a screenshot

arr = np.array(image)           # turn it into an array

result = np.where(np.all(arr == color, axis=2))     # find the colour in the array
pos = result[1][0], result[0][0]                    # the first index is y or x, note that numpy array has y
# as 0 and x as [1]. The second index is what index to grab, so in this case the first occurance of the colour is used
pyautogui.moveTo(*pos)                              # first moving and then clicking is more reliable for me
pyautogui.click()
```